# how to find free slot from available slot and booked slot

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one is the available time slot and another booked time slot with start date time and end date time. I want to return free time slots.

Table 1

```
available_slots
start_datetime      |end_datetime
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 05:00:00 |2020-01-14 06:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 06:00:00 |2020-01-14 07:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 07:00:00 |2020-01-14 08:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 08:00:00 |2020-01-14 09:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 09:00:00 |2020-01-14 10:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 10:00:00 |2020-01-14 11:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 11:00:00 |2020-01-14 12:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 12:00:00 |2020-01-14 13:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 13:00:00 |2020-01-14 14:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 14:00:00 |2020-01-14 15:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 15:00:00 |2020-01-14 16:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 16:00:00 |2020-01-14 17:00:00
```

Table 2

```
booked_slots
start_datetime      |end_datetime
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 07:00:00 |2020-01-14 08:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 13:00:00 |2020-01-14 14:15:00
-----------------------------------------
```

Result Should be

```
Free slots
start_datetime      |end_datetime
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 05:00:00 |2020-01-14 06:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 06:00:00 |2020-01-14 07:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 08:00:00 |2020-01-14 09:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 09:00:00 |2020-01-14 10:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 10:00:00 |2020-01-14 11:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 11:00:00 |2020-01-14 12:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 12:00:00 |2020-01-14 13:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 15:00:00 |2020-01-14 16:00:00
-----------------------------------------
2020-01-14 16:00:00 |2020-01-14 17:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM table2  
                  WHERE table2.start_datetime = table1.start_datetime 
                  AND table2.end_datetime = table1.end_datetime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using a LEFT JOIN like this:

```sql
    SELECT * 
      FROM available_slots A
 LEFT JOIN booked_slots B
        ON (B.start_datetime = A.start_datetime AND B.end_datetime = A.end_datetime)
     WHERE B.start_datetime IS NULL
```